# Add a method to a model field declared in Meta class

Tags: django, django-filter

Is it possible to add a [method](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#method) to a field declared in the FilterSet Meta class, that processes the value given before filtering?

In the following

```py
class MoldelAFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = { 
            'name': ['exact', 'contain'], 
            'ts': ['exact', 'gt', 'lt'] 
        }
```

I want to process the value passed to 'ts' (p.e: '2020-11-02') before filtering

Comment: No, thats not possible. You have to explicitly define the fields with the `method` parameter

Comment: @JPG Hmmm, and how would you do that in this case?  
Btw, thank you for the answer :)

Comment: as I said, I would go for separate fields

Comment: @JPG Yeah I understood that, maybe my question-comment wasn't clear sorry.
I'm new to django-filter and after reading the docs it wasn't clear to me how can I do that (separate fields). Because when I try to declare the fields before class Meta I get the following `AssertionError: Setting 'Meta.model' without either 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' has been deprecated since 0.15.0 and is now disallowed. Add an explicit 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' to the ModelAFilter class.`